# Xamarin - reading JSON file and reading the values

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, json.net

everyone ! I'm new in Xamarin. I've this json file...

```
{
"debug":true,
"sequence":[
  "p1"
],
"pages":[
  {
     "pageId":"p1",
     "type":"seq",
     "elements":[
        {
           "type":"smallVideo",
           "width":300,
           "height":300,
           "top":0,
           "left":0,
           "file":"xxx.mp4"
        }
     ]
  }
],
 "index":[
  {
     "width":300,
     "height":300,
     "top":0,
     "left":0,
     "goTo":"p1"
  }
]
}
```

And this is my simple code...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

JObject elements = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("elements.json"));
Console.WriteLine(elements);
```

Ok, I can see on my output screen the whole JSON file. Fine...
But I'd like to read any value just like javascript, examples...

elements.debug (true)

elements.pages[0].pageId

So, I need to retrieve values based on the key/path like it's usual in Javascript. Any clue ?

ty !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is a little bit different from js, here you need to declare objects.
In your case you need to create new class called ElementsObj and your object would be this class instance:

```
public class ElementsObj
{
    public bool debug { get; set; }
    public List<string> sequence { get; set; }
    public List<Page> pages { get; set; }
    public List<Index> index { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int left { get; set; }
    public string file { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public string pageId { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Element> elements { get; set; }
}

public class Index
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int left { get; set; }
    public string goTo { get; set; }
}
```

In future use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate classes from JSON file.

Later you can deserialize your JSON to this object.
I'd suggest Newtonsoft lib to do this:

```
ElementsObj tmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ElementsObj>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Crap ! I was wondering something like your solution, but I tough with myself: Noooooo ! Plz !!! It's probably an easy way to archive this !!!! But it's okay ! tyvm, Zaven !

Answer (score 0):

**1) Option** create an `object` that reflects your JSON structure:

```
public class Element
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int left { get; set; }
    public string file { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public string pageId { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<Element> elements { get; set; }
}

public class Index
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int top { get; set; }
    public int left { get; set; }
    public string goTo { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public bool debug { get; set; }
    public List<string> sequence { get; set; }
    public List<Page> pages { get; set; }
    public List<Index> index { get; set; }
}

MyObject parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(File.ReadAllText("elements.json"));

var debug = parsed.debug;
```

**2) Option** using `dynamic`

```
dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(File.ReadAllText("elements.json"));

var debug = dynamic.debug;
```